# subtracting two adjacent values in a column

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data file includes 21 columns. I want to subtract two adjacent values in columns between 10 to 18 and write the results after latest column. For example I have a file with the following columns:

```
    1  2  3  ... 10  11 ... 18 ... 21 //column 
    0  0  0  ... 0   1  ... 0  ... 0
    0  0  0  ... 1   2  ... 18 ... 0
    0  0  0  ... 10  12 ... 38 ... 0
.
.
.
```

I want to change above data to the following using an awk script:

```
    1  2  3  ... 10 11 ... 18 ...21 22 23 ...  30 //column 
    0  0  0  ... 0  1  ... 0 ... 0  0  1  ...  0  // such as first row of 10:18
    0  0  0  ... 1  2  ... 18 ...0  1  1  ...  18
    0  0  0  ... 10 12 ... 40 ...0  9  10 ...  22
.
.
.
```

.
As you see, columns 22 is calculated by subtracting i+1 th from i th row. It means the elements of 22th column are calculated from 10th column as:

```
... 10 ... 22 ... //column

... 0  ... 0 ...
... 1  ... 1 ...
... 10 ... 9 ...
.
.
.
```

.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Expecting your reply and Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Can anyone help me in this regard?` -- if you tell us what did you try?

Comment: Try describing what did you tried, why it failed, how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
awk -f sub.awk input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is your input data file and `sub.awk` is

```
{ 
    printf "%s%s", $0, FS

    for (i=10;i<=18;i++) {
       printf "%s%s", $i-prevline[i], FS
       prevline[i]=$i
    }
    printf "\n"
}
```